# Broken pipe with python requests lib

Tags: python, bash

I'am running in a issue that, if I run my script from my computer it works well, but when the script runs in another server by BASH it return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 361, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 936, in _send_output
    self.send(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 908, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

What I'am doing:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
html_content = session.post('http://example.com/content.html', data=d, cookies=session.cookies.get_dict(), headers=headers)
```

I'am receiving an AJAX HTML result for each page I need to iterate, I reach to page 2 but when he try to get the third page the error show up.

Comment: Can you reproduce it every time? Does the server have any useful log messages? What's the response code?

Comment: See this: Broken pipe Exception · Issue #2422 · kennethreitz/requests · GitHub
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2422

Comment: @paragbaxi I'am not passing files, but I'am sending some requests with big hashed parameters to a ASP server, the curious thing is, why in my computer runs smoothly and when I try to run in another machine it bugs, Btw I can't see the server logs.